# How to convert array of numpy objects to an array containing the elements of every object?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy objects array with shape (60000,) and each of the 60000 elements is a (32,32,3)array. My question is how to convert the (60000,) array to a (32,32,3,60000) array.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: you means (6000, 32, 32, 3) -> (32, 32, 3, 6000)?

Comment: Not exactly, the way data was generated the array is a numpy object array. data.shape prints (6000,) and data[1].shape print (32,32,3). I want data.shape to print (60000,32,32,3).

Comment: Try `np.stack`.

Comment: concatenate and reshape worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
import numpy as np

class Obj():
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i = i

l = np.array([np.array([Obj(i) for i in range(64*3)]).reshape(8,8,3)
 for _ in range(100)])

print(l.shape)
#Output: (100, 8, 8, 3)

print(np.transpose(l,(1,2,3,0)).shape)
#Output: (8, 8, 3, 100)
```